# For Each Loop Not working

Tags: java, mysql

Here is my code -

```
    StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();
    queryString.append("select m.user_message "); 
    queryString.append("from message m");
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString.toString());

    List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
    System.out.println(results);
    for (Object[] result : results) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

It prints right answer for "System.out.println(results);", But don't enter into  for each loop. 
Here error is :-

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Comment: try for (String result : results) {

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the exception you got, it looks like `query.getResultList()` returns a `List<String>`, not `List<Object[]>`. Change your code to

```
List<String> results = query.getResultList();
System.out.println(results);
for (String result : results) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: . I got this.. When selecting (select m.id) it returns string and when selecting two or more (select m.id,m.message) , it returns object.. Thanks ..

Comment: From the doc for the method: "query execution will result in each row of the SQL result being returned as a result of type Object[] (or a result of type Object if there is only one column in the select list.)"

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the array wrong

Do instead:

```
for (Object[] result : results) {
        for (Object obj : result) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

**OR EVEN BETTER**

```
 for (Object[] result : results) {
           Arrays.toString(result));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that there are results within the returned list by changing `System.out.println(results);` into something like `System.out.println(results ==null ? "empty", results.size());`

To me it seems that it is entering the loop because of the reported exception `java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;` but as Erna indicated within his answer above, the returned list might be a list of Strings instead of an array of Objects.